# Get fields[].getName() as accessible String?

Tags: android, string

I'm working on a small function that loads all files from the 'raw' folder and then, based on a prefix, determines wether or not they should be saved in a Vector. This in preparation for a 'level-loading' mechanic I want to use for the game I'm making. The function I have works:

```
public void LoadRaws(){
    Field[] fields=R.raw.class.getFields();
    for(int count=0; count < fields.length; count++){
        StringStorage.add(fields[count].getName());
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < StringStorage.size(); i++){
        Log.i("Asset", StringStorage.get(i));
    }
}
```

The Log.i(); function neatly prints the filename to my LogCat. However, when I try something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < StringStorage.size()-1; i++){
    Message(StringStorage.get(i));
}
```

To push a message-box containing the String, I get a nullPointerException. Here's the log:

```
11-19 14:08:51.881: E/AndroidRuntime(4161): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-19 14:08:51.881: E/AndroidRuntime(4161): Process: com.example.whoops, PID: 4161
11-19 14:08:51.881: E/AndroidRuntime(4161): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.whoops/com.example.whoops.Game}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-19 14:08:51.881: E/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2439)
11-19 14:08:51.881: E/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495)
11-19 14:08:51.881: E/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:153)
11-19 14:08:51.881: E/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349)
11-19 14:08:51.881: E/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-19 14:08:51.881: E/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
11-19 14:08:51.881: E/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5633)
11-19 14:08:51.881: E/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-19 14:08:51.881: E/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-19 14:08:51.881: E/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:896)
11-19 14:08:51.881: E/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:712)
11-19 14:08:51.881: E/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-19 14:08:51.881: E/AndroidRuntime(4161): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-19 14:08:51.881: E/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:159)
11-19 14:08:51.881: E/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:104)
11-19 14:08:51.881: E/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at android.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:143)
11-19 14:08:51.881: E/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.<init>(AlertDialog.java:360)
11-19 14:08:51.881: E/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at com.example.whoops.UtilLib.Message(UtilLib.java:186)
11-19 14:08:51.881: E/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at com.example.whoops.LevelStorage.LoadRaws(LevelStorage.java:35)
11-19 14:08:51.881: E/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at com.example.whoops.Game.onCreate(Game.java:55)
11-19 14:08:51.881: E/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5312)
11-19 14:08:51.881: E/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
11-19 14:08:51.881: E/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
11-19 14:08:51.881: E/AndroidRuntime(4161):     ... 11 more
```

I have no idea why it does this, as it is crucial I get the names before defining the IDs of these files. Does anyone have an idea why I get this error? And how do I solve it?

-Zubaja

Comment: What is the 186 line of your `UtilLib.java` file? Have you tested that for **any** `i`, it is not `null`?

Comment: for(int i = 0; i < StringStorage.size()-1; i++){
    Message("MESSAGE"+StringStorage.get(i));
}

Comment: @nKn this: new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("").setMessage(message).setNeutralButton("OK", null).show();

Comment: The error is not with your data but with misusing a UI component, possibly an improperly initialized one.

Comment: @khurram same nullPointerException, sadly.

Comment: @ChrisStratton How would you propose I fix the issue, then? I also tried a simple 'if' like: "if(StringStorage.get(i).charAt(x) == '')" but that doesn't work either. I don't know if that, too, is a UI thing?

Comment: possible that the context you are passing to the alert dialog is null.

Comment: @cesztoszule That was indeed the issue. If I 'Message()' from a different class that accesses the 'StringStorage' vector, I get the names.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for(int i = 0; i < StringStorage.size()-1; i++){
try{
     Message(StringStorage.get(i));
   }catch(Exception e){
    Log.i("Error at Index :",""+i);
   }
}
```

you can catch null pointer and detect where exactly it comes.

Comment: That does help, but it did not fix my error. For each variable in StringStorage, it gives the 'Log.i' message.

Answer (score -1):

I've managed to fix it myself, and here's how:

```
public void LoadRaws(){
    Field[] fields=R.raw.class.getFields();
    for(int count=0; count < fields.length; count++){
        StringStorage.add(fields[count].getName());
    }
}
```

The above functions from 'LevelStorage' works fine. However, when trying to access the data inside the Vector from the same class, it gives me an error.
I then called the function from my 'Game' class, and then tried looping through the vector, and guess what happened? I got the filenames.
Thanks for everyone that helped me, you da best!